# I get a type error with django-simple-history

Tags: django-simple-history

This only seems to happen when I try to view some model objects.
I get the following when I visit the history page for an object in the admin page:

```
__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

Full traceback:
https://dpaste.com/EQMTDXK5H

EDIT: Looks like the issue was that the **str** for my model was returning an integer, which Django seemed happy with but django-simple-history was not. I added str() into my **str** to convert the integer to a string and all works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code [here](https://github.com/jazzband/django-simple-history/blob/b43890f729b624ccca1d935db0922679d34999cb/simple_history/models.py#L443) and [here](https://github.com/jazzband/django-simple-history/blob/master/simple_history/templates/simple_history/_object_history_list.html#L22)

Seems that the `__str__` of the HistoryRecords module looks for the `__str__` of your model to build it's own, and also uses it on the template for the history build.

Check that your model has `__str__` implemented.

Comment: Thanks Joac. I had a complex __str__ that returned different values depending upon the content of the model. Sometimes it would return an integer. I converted the integer to a string using str() and all works now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.